# Angular input binding does not work correctly

Tags: angular, angular6, inputbinding

I have a really strange problem. I have multiple instances of a component with almost the same input properties. One of them (the first 'doc-diagnose-form' component in the code below) is ignored when one of the input properties change. All other component instances (created with *ngFor) become destroyed and newly instanciated when one of the input properties change. How can this happen?

Info: I use Angular 6

**Parent Component .html:**

```
// Component that is not changed
<doc-diagnose-form [pc]="pc" [diagnose]="pc.pdx"
                 (onChangeDiagnose)="changeDiagnose($event)" (onDeleteDiagnose)="deleteDiagnose($event)">

</doc-diagnose-form>


// Components that become updated
<doc-diagnose-form [pc]="pc" [diagnose]="diagnose" *ngFor="let diagnose of pc.diagnoses"
                 (onChangeDiagnose)="changeDiagnose($event)" (onDeleteDiagnose)="deleteDiagnose($event)">

</doc-diagnose-form>
```

**Parent Component .ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input, Output, EventEmitter, OnChanges, SimpleChanges } from '@angular/core';
import { Diagnose, DiagnoseArray, PatientCase, PrimaryDiagnoseArray } from '../../../models/models';

@Component({
    selector: 'doc-diagnose-list',
    templateUrl: './diagnose-list.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./diagnose-list.component.css']
})
export class DiagnoseListComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges {

  @Input() diagnoses?: DiagnoseArray;
  @Input() pc?: PatientCase;
  @Input() primaryDiagnoses?: PrimaryDiagnoseArray;
  @Output() addCoding = new EventEmitter();
  @Output() modifyDiagnose = new EventEmitter();
  @Output() removeDiagnose = new EventEmitter();

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {}

  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
    console.log('OnChanges: ', changes);
  }

  changeDiagnose(value): void {
    this.modifyDiagnose.emit(value);
  }

  deleteDiagnose(value): void {
    this.removeDiagnose.emit(value);
  }
}
```

I would be glad if someone could help me!

EDIT: 
The diagnose-form component looks like this:

**diagnose-form.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormBuilder } from '@angular/forms';
import { PatientCase, Diagnose, CatalogElement} from '../../../models/models';
import { CatalogService } from '../../../services/catalog.service';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { LoggerService } from '../../../services/logger.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'doc-diagnose-form',
  templateUrl: './diagnose-form.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./diagnose-form.component.css'],
})
export class DiagnoseFormComponent implements OnInit {

  diagnoseForm: FormGroup;
  CATALOG = 'icds';
  CATALOG_VERSION = 'ICD10-GM-2016';
  codeChangeLog: string[] = [];

  @Input() pc: PatientCase;
  @Input() diagnose: Diagnose;
  @Output() onChangeDiagnose = new EventEmitter();
  @Output() onDeleteDiagnose = new EventEmitter();

  constructor (
    private fb: FormBuilder,
    private catalogService: CatalogService,
    private logger: LoggerService ) {
    this.createForm();
    this.logCodeChange();
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.logger.log('OnInit DiagnoseForm');
    this.getCatalogElement(this.diagnose).subscribe(success => {
      this.diagnoseForm.setValue({
        code: this.diagnose.code,
      });
      this.diagnose.text = success.text;
      this.logger.log('Successfully set initial form values!', success)
    }, error => {
      this.diagnose.text = 'Ungültige Diagnose!';
      this.logger.error('Failed to populate the form!', error);
    });
  }

  createForm(): void {
    this.diagnoseForm = this.fb.group({
      code: '',
    });
  }

  logCodeChange(): void {
    const codeControl = this.diagnoseForm.get('code');
    codeControl.valueChanges.forEach(
      (value: string) => {
        this.codeChangeLog.push(value);
        this.logger.log('CodeChangeLog: ', this.codeChangeLog)
      }
    );
  }

  isPrimaryDiagnose(): boolean {
    return this.pc.all_diagnoses.indexOf(this.diagnose) === 0;
  }

  /**
   * Retrieves the catalog element that corresponds to the diagnose.
   *
   * @param value the diagnose form value to find catalog element
   * @returns {Observable<CatalogElement>} a catalog element as observable
   */
  getCatalogElement(value: any): Observable<CatalogElement> {
    return new Observable(observer => {
      this.catalogService.getSingleElementForTypeByCode(this.CATALOG, this.CATALOG_VERSION, value.code).subscribe(
        (catalogElement: CatalogElement) => {
          observer.next(catalogElement);
          observer.complete();
        },
        error => {
          this.logger.error('An error occurred while getting catalog element!', error);
          observer.error(error);
          observer.complete();
        })
    });
  };

  /**
   * Removes the diagnose from the diagnose array of the current patient case.
   */
  deleteDiagnose(): void {
    this.onDeleteDiagnose.emit({diagnose: this.diagnose, isPrimaryDiagnose: this.isPrimaryDiagnose()});
  };

  /**
   * Saves a new patient case with the updated diagnose array.
   */
  saveDiagnose(code: string, text: string): void {
    this.onChangeDiagnose.emit({code: code, text: text, oldDiagnose: this.diagnose, isPrimaryDiagnose: this.isPrimaryDiagnose()})
  }

  /**
   * Updates the current diagnose.
   *
   * @param value The diagnose form that contains the code of the diagnose.
   */
  updateDiagnose(value: any): void {
    if (value.code !== '' && value.code !== this.diagnose.code) {
      this.getCatalogElement(value).subscribe(success => {
          this.saveDiagnose(success.code, success.text);
          this.logger.log('Successfully updated diagnose!', success);
        },
        error => {
          this.logger.error('An error occurred while update diagnose!', error)
        });
    }
  };
}
```

Comment: What's the implementation of `doc-diagnose-form`?

Comment: I added the code of the diagnose-form-component to my post.